# How to convert this to onClick vs regular hover?

Tags: onclick

Here is a Fiddle, to show my current state: (attempting onClick())
http://jsfiddle.net/D5N4f/7/

```
$('.associationLinks').click(function () {
    alert("I've been clicked"); //test to see if click is working
    //$(this).next().toggle();
    $(this.content).toggle();
    //$(this .content').css("display", "block");
});
```

here is a version of the working HOVER, that I need to convert to onClick:

http://jsfiddle.net/D5N4f/6/

This is working fine.. however.. on HOVER is just not practical for my use.. I need to change it to onClick..but have the same behavior.

Do I need to use jQuery for this?  (I havent been able to get it to work)

the content I want displayed starts off as display:none..

I have tried to show(), toggle() and even .css("display", "block");  (maybe Im not targeting things correctly?)

the last part of this (since there will be MANY links set-up like this) is to close the previous 'SHOW' content.. when I click on a new link.. (ie: only having one content box displayed at a time vs. having several open at same time!)

Please use the fiddle example instead of just random code suggestions!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the following CSS:

```
/*.associationLinks:hover .content {
    display:block;
}*/
```

I also use a .children() selector to get the content div to display, and I change it's CSS on a click.

Is this closer to what you want? Hiding the image is a bit tricker, and I have an idea for that but I'm not sure if you need it.

Comment: Thanks, I had gotten it working just now this way (although Im not sure which way is better or why?)

http://jsfiddle.net/D5N4f/13/

I just need a way to CLOSE the previously open one when I click on a new/different link. Ideas?  thanks!

Comment: What do you mean which way?

Comment: Also...it seems that when I click a link to open/display the content under it... the whole page goes back to the top?  How can I fix this?
Why would toggling the DIV container like that bring me to the TOP oy my page again?  (defeats the purpose if I have to scroll down to the link I just clicked to see the content dispalyed?

Comment: @Klye Sum 
I mean if I click on link 1 to display content.. then I click link 2..it should close link 1's displayed content (as well as displaying link 2's content)  make sense?  Did you check out my fiddle?

If I use the CSS to set that DIV to display:none, is there any way to use toggle or show/hide then after? or do I need to target the CSS and change the display value only?    (which is why I switched over to jQuery hiding all those .content DIVs vs using the CSS display:none)

Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying you only want one image/div to display at a time when you click? If so, try look at my fiddle again. I made an update that hides the other div when you click.

Comment: ahh.. I didnt see you edited it.  Yes, that is almost correct. Except that now clicking the 'same' link not longer toggles its own content.

check this fiddle even though I am using hide and to display like your approach: http://jsfiddle.net/D5N4f/17/

Comment: if you un-comment that one line in the jQuery box, you can see the difference between the two...  one DOES close any open 'display divs' (which is what I want)..  but when you click on the same link it doesnt close itself  (make sense?)

the other way (line commented out)..its the opposite, DOES toggle itself (which I also want), but does NOT close any open 'display divs'...

I need both, which I have not been able to work out. :)
I posted latest fiddle (17)

Thanks

Comment: Updated my solution. Let me know if this is better.

Comment: nice job, functionaly, it works exactly how/what I was asking for! *(answer given).. bonus points if you can use 'my' fiddle link....so I can use toggle()..or even show()/hide()  (and possibly add some animation/effects or something)...  I tried to do a conditional check myself...(doing a check on the visibility..like so)

    if($(this).siblings.('.content').is(':visible')){}

maybe using siblings is the wrong approach?

current fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D5N4f/21/

Comment: Hmmm you could probably get siblings to work with some tweaking, I didn't look too carefully. If it's not working, try re-examine your use of is() with :visible. I'm no web development star (half a year of experience), but to me the top priority is to just get it working. I've been able to make some decently complex webapps with careful id and class selection combined with parent() and children(). Anyways, I've edited my fiddle one more time. I'm not too good with jQuery, but I'm confident you could also make animate() or show()/hide() work. However, toggle() provides a decent animation.