# css hover to onclick conversation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

I was wondering if anyone could help me out. I'm trying to make a simple folio site, and I have this link in the top nav that when clicked on would appear a horizontal menu underneath the header. So far I have goten it to work with just css, but I don't like how the menu appears when hovered, it would look much more professional if it appeared when clicked and stayed there until you click on the same link again. if anyone could help me that'll be great. I've tried all sorts of java tutorials and won't very successful I didn't fully understand it.

```
<header>
    <a class="home" href="../index.htm" title="Home Page"></a>
    <a class="to_nav" href="#nav" ></a>
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="#top">
            <h1>Deeran</h1>
            <span>Graphic Design</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <nav>
        <ul class="drop">
            <li>
                <a id="menu"></a>
                <ul class="hide">
                    <li><a href="#folio">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact/Hire</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

And here's the css

```
nav {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
nav ul li a#menu {
    display: block;
    width: 67px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    margin-top: 9px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

nav ul ul.hide {
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 10px 0 0;
    text-indent: none;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
}

nav ul ul.hide li {margin: 0;}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    }
```

if there was one simple way to convert that one :hover function to onClick I would be very grateful :)

Comment: If you set up the menu correctly, hovering is easier to access than clicking

Comment: @Huangism I agree, but i just hate the behavior in touch devices

Comment: @sabithpocker yes for touch devices js is needed to alter the behaviour to use click or touch events, like the one on lexus.ca

Comment: check this thread out it is very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20409319/how-to-convert-this-to-onclick-vs-regular-hover

Answer (score 2):

make

```
nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    }
```

to

```
nav ul li.active > ul {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    }
```

Then use javascript to add a class `active` onClick.

What makes SO wonderful is that we can refer to similar cases easily :)

For javascript part please refer this answer .

[Add/Remove class onclick with JavaScript no librarys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757717/add-remove-class-onclick-with-javascript-no-librarys)

Comment: what would be the javascript I would need? I'm sorry i'm not very expereinced with java

Comment: please check the link in the answer, there is a very similar case. Please ask if there is anything not clear in that.

Answer (score 0):

The 'click' event cannot be listened for with css. Remove your :hover rule and add some JavaScript. In the code you provided, you don't have anything in the #menu element for the user to click on, so I added some text for the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/Fc75u/

JavaScript:

```
var toggle = document.getElementById('menu');
var menu = document.getElementsByClassName('hide');
toggle.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    menu[0].style.display == "block" ? menu[0].style.display = "none" : menu[0].style.display = "block";
});
```

jQuery:

```
$('#menu').click(function () {
    $('.hide').toggle();
});
```

Comment: I added the plain JavaScript solution so you don't have to mess with adding jQuery. Check the fiddle.