# Display submenu on click in pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

> See further below for solution

I built a dropdown menu where the submenu currently appears on hover thanks to the following CSS:

```
.main-menu ul li:hover > ul { display: block; }
```

However my design requires the submenu to display on click and remain visible until the user clicks elsewhere on the page (or on the close button in this example). Based on a few similar questions here, e.g. [css hover to onclick conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22510535/css-hover-to-onclick-conversation/22510659#22510659?newreg=3cbd4608031d4ca1a3c9d15f9f6b89f6), it looks like I need to use JavaScript `setAttribute` to add class `active` on click:

```
.main-menu ul li.active > ul { display: block; }
```

The examples I've seen achieve this by using the below JS, which gets the element by ID, but I'm obviously unable to give the same ID to each of my submenus. I could give different IDs to each and then write a new function each time but is there a better way to "get" these elements? I've tested with classes and `querySelectorAll()` to try and target the exact tags but I'm obviously missing something. I'd be so grateful if anyone could point me in the right direction.

```
window.onload = init;
function init()
{
    document.getElementById('openSubmenu').onclick   = openSubmenu;
    document.getElementById('closeSubmenu').onclick  = closeSubmenu;
}

function openSubmenu()
{
    document.getElementById('openSubmenu').setAttribute('class','active');
}

function closeSubmenu()
{
    document.getElementById('openSubmenu').removeAttribute('class','active');
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="closeSubmenu">Close submenu</div>
<nav>
  <div class="main-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li id="openSubmenu"><a href="#">Dropdown 1</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">First tier</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">First tier</a></li>
        </ul>  
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown 2</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">First tier</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">First tier</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">First tier</a></li>
       </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.main-menu {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

.main-menu ul {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.main-menu ul li { display: inline-block; }

.main-menu li a {
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #494949;
}

/* Hide dropdowns by default */

.main-menu ul ul {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #c6c6c6;
}

/* Display Dropdowns on Hover */

.main-menu ul li:hover > ul { display: block; }

/* Display Dropdowns on Click */

.main-menu ul li.active > ul { display: block; }
```

> SOLUTION
>
> With the below code the relevant submenus open
>   on click, close when you click again on the submenu name and close when you
>   click on a regular "non-submenu" element.
>
> HTML
>
> ```
> <nav>
>     <ul>
>       <li class="menuItem"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
>       <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Dropdown 1</a>
>         <ul>
>           <li><a href="#">First tier</a></li>
>           <li><a href="#">First tier</a></li>
>         </ul>  
>       </li>
>       <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Dropdown 2</a>
>         <ul>
>           <li><a href="#">First tier</a></li>
>           <li><a href="#">First tier</a></li>
>           <li><a href="#">First tier</a></li>
>        </ul>
>       </li>
>       <li class="menuItem"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
>       <li class="menuItem"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
>     </ul>
> </nav>
> ```
>
> CSS
>
> ```
> nav {
>   width: 100%;
>   left: 0;
> }
>
> nav ul {
>   position: relative;
>   text-align: center;
> }
>
> nav ul li { display: inline-block; }
>
> nav li a {
>   line-height: 40px;
>   padding: 10px 20px;
>   text-transform: uppercase;
>   text-decoration: none;
>   color: #494949;
> }
>
> /* Hide dropdowns by default */
>
> nav ul ul {
>   width: 100%;
>   position: absolute;
>   display: none;
>   left: 0;
>   background-color: #c6c6c6;
> }
>
> /* Display Dropdowns on Click */
>
> nav ul li.active > ul {
>   display: block;
> }
> ```
>
> JS
>
> ```
> window.onload = init;
> function init()
> {
>   // set-up regular buttons
>   var menuItemElements = document.getElementsByClassName('menuItem');
>   for (var i = 0; i < menuItemElements.length; i++) {
>     menuItemElements[i].onclick = resetSubmenus;
>   }
>   // set-up buttons with submenu
>   resetSubmenus();
> }
>
> function openSubmenu()
>   {
>     resetSubmenus();
>     this.setAttribute('class','submenu active');
>     this.onclick = resetSubmenus;
>   }
>
> function resetSubmenus()
>   {
>     var submenuElements = document.getElementsByClassName('submenu');
>     for (var i = 0; i < submenuElements.length; i++) {
>       submenuElements[i].setAttribute('class','submenu');
>       submenuElements[i].onclick = openSubmenu;
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Please add your solution as answer, it would be nice to include relevant code in directly in answer and not only a link to cod pen, also remove "Resolved" from question, we use "accept" on answer to understand what worked for OP see [tour] to learn more

Answer (score 0):

Without giving you the exact code....I would probably do something like this:

Give a class of `dropdown` to the two dropdowns. Give a clas of `submenu` to the sub-menus.

Attach a click handler to class `dropdown` and on click, using the keyword `this`, I would differentiate which one was clicked and add the class of `active` to it.

I would have a CSS class called `active` that had the proper CSS required of an open dropdown menu to display correctly.

something like:

```
.active .submenu{
  */ submenu CSS */
}
```

Then, I need to account for sliding back up, so when any dropdown is clicked again (just like above), or maybe anywhere on the page outside of the dropdowns as well, I would first remove the `active` class from all dropdown elements, then add it to the new one that was clicked, so only the one clicked.

Not sure how much that will help you, but there you go :)